# console.log is unable to fetch port variable, i've provided the screenshots

Tags: javascript, node.js, console.log

In my javascript program I've already declared the port variable, but it is not working when I use `$port` inside `console.log` function.

[Here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRInZ.png) the snapshot of my console.

Comment: Please provide your actual code instead of a screenshot.

Answer (score 2):

Use backticks instead of single quotes:

```
console.log(`Text ${variable}`);
```

instead of:

```
console.log('Text ${variable}');
```

See:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Answer (score 0):

Instead of single quotes '${port}' try to use backticks ``